# How to run a function with all strings?

Tags: string, bash

I'm trying to create a program that run a function that creates maximum N length strings, with some characters
For example with input "AB" (A and B characters possible) and 3 (maximum length): 
`A AA AAA AAB AB ABA ABB ... BB BBA BBB`
(the order doesn't matter)

I found this:
[Bash string handling (char at index and concatenation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349702/bash-string-handling-char-at-index-and-concatenation)
The answers only apply for 2-length strings, I want to run it with eg 10 length, and 20 characters. (I have time to run this :) )
Is there a way to do this?
And if so, how to?

Comment: You probably don't want to run it with 20 characters, because even if there are only 2 characters to choose from, you're running at (round figures) 1 million 20 character strings, plus 0.5 million 19 character strings, ... which ends up at about 2 million strings output.

Comment: For the list of N character strings, capture the output of the list of N-1 character strings, then echo each captured string followed by each possible extra character.  Start with N=1.  The fact that you have to capture the previous output is going to eat up memory, though.

Comment: I have time to run this, but the memory is finite. :)

Comment: The order would be great to be 0, 1, 2, ... length (A B AA AB BA BB AAA... ), but you're right, Jonathan, it's a "bit" great... I have to rethink that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Bash solution:

```
chars='{A,B}'                         # characters to use
cnt=6                                 # maximum length
str=''
for (( CNTR=0; CNTR<$cnt; CNTR+=1 )); do
  str=$str$chars
  eval echo "$str"
done
```

The character list can be expanded, e.g.

```
chars='{A,B,C}'
```

The output:

```
A B
AA AB BA BB
AAA AAB ABA ABB BAA BAB BBA BBB
AAAA AAAB AABA AABB ABAA ABAB ABBA ABBB BAAA BAAB BABA BABB BBAA BBAB BBBA BBB
```

Needs a few seconds for cnt=20 and set {A,B}.